# Is there a way to get the name of the file only from tkFileDialog?

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I have this code:

```
filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="lists/custom/", filetypes=(("Word list",
                                        "*.tldr"), ("All files", "*.*")))
```

If I had a file called "dog.tldr", is there a way to get only the file name of it instead of having a directory in front of it? Right now `filename` outputs something like

/dir/blah/dog.tldr

But I only want the `dog.tldr`. Is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.path.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.split):

```
In [83]: full_path = "/dir/blah/dog.tldr"

In [84]: os.path.split(full_path)
Out[84]: ('/dir/blah', 'dog.tldr')

In [85]: os.path.split(full_path)[1]
Out[85]: 'dog.tldr'
```

Comment: `os.path.basename()` would have been nicer.